# EntityFramework - Group by unordered pair in LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that contains 4 columns `**(User_from, User_to,Message,Date)**`

I need to get the last message a user have in all participant chats.

```
var all = from m in db.Peers
                      where m.User_Id_To == id || m.User_Id_From == id
                      group m by new { m.User_Id_To, m.User_Id_From } into g
                      select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

The code above works to get the last message for each id,
but still having an issue.

Consider having this 2 records below :

```
 User_from     User_To    Content   Date

    1             2          hi       01-01-2018
    2             1          wlc      02-02-2018
```

When I am trying to use my query I am getting both records. I just need the last one according to date.

Comment: this will only return one value, i need one value for each conversation that user participated in

Comment: And why group at all? It seems you can just filter by id (like you do now), and order by date, then take first one (again like you do now), without grouping.

Comment: ordering by date will only get the last message for the user ,not for all chats that belongs to that user.

Comment: @yazan I posted an answer. Is that what you want or I misunderstood you or it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `GroupBy` you can create a conditional key so when you want to group by a pair of values where order dosen't matter you can construct key as an anonymous type with the first property set to min value and the second to max value.

```
var all = from m in db.Peers
    where m.User_Id_To == id || m.User_Id_From == id
    group m by new 
    { 
        Min = m.User_Id_To < m.User_Id_From ? m.User_Id_To : m.User_Id_From,     
        Max = m.User_Id_To > m.User_Id_From ? m.User_Id_To : m.User_Id_From 
    } 
    into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```